# Redirect PHP from Public to main root folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Good day to you all. I'm trying to redirect my index.php from the public folder to the main or root folder.

I've added the .htaccess file with the following code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project-Folder/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

But my images and js in the src folder are not showing up, any fix, please?

**Update**

My images and other assets are working now. I just needed to move the assets folder from the src folder to the public folder as well. The  `src`  is working well as well.

Comment: JS/CS rewrite/redirect:
You may need to use base tag to fix your js and other relative resources. If you are linking js files using a relative path then the file will obviously get a 404 because its looking for URL path. for example if the URL path is /file/ instead of file.html then your relative resources are loading from /file/ which is not a directory but rewritten html file. To fix this make your links absolute or use base tag. In the header of your webpage add this `<base href="/">` so that your relative links can load from the correct location.

Comment: Considering that rewriting and redirecting is happening fine, if yes then try with above comment once.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 thanks for your response. I tried adding that  ``` <base href="/"> ``` to the header of the file but it didn't solve the issue. Can you specify how to go about it?

Please note that my public and src are on the root folder.

Comment: Ok, could you please do mention samples urls eg: `http://localhost:80/test/blabla` which one is working and which one not, so that we can get a better picture of question, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this code in your site root .htaccess:

```bash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project-Folder/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteRule ^(?!public/|src/).*$ public/$0 [L,NC]
```

Note that we are now skipping `src/` directory from your last rule.

Comment: Thanks, @anubhava, I don't want to skip the SRC folder. I need to include the src folder and all its files in the rewrite rule.

Comment: Is `src` folder inside the `public/` fulder?

Comment: No, Src is outside the public folder/

Comment: What is full URl of css or ja file? This rule change is required if src is not inside public